# For Azure B2C, is there a way to send the user principal name via claims?

Tags: c#, azure, blazor, azure-ad-b2c

I'm having some issues with getting the currently signed-in user's username from Azure b2c to my Blazor web app. Essentially, I want to make a username account where a username is the User Principal Name. I was originally using an email sign-up policy with a display name as the username. However, b2c doesn't enforce display names to be unique, so there's an inherent issue with that. No claim comes back with a username in it, so I have no way in my Blazor app to keep tabs on who is signed in or display their username. There are a few options I can do, and I'm curious which one is the easiest to implement/how to implement it, cause I've been ripping my hair out with this the past few hours.

- On b2c account creation, take User Principal Name and also make it the display name
- Have the user principal name be sent via claims (Not sure how to do this)
- Do Email sign up with Display Names, but somehow enforce b2c to ensure display names are unique
- Some other way to have a unique display name for users from b2c

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using local account in b2c ? user flows / custom policies ? Are you talking about `signInNames.userName` ? So you want a unique username that is the same as display name ?

Comment: As of right now, I'm using local accounts in b2c. On the sign up/sign in user flow, under identity providers local accounts you can select 'Email Signup' or 'User ID Signup'. 

If I choose Email Signup, Email is the unique identitifer, however, I want my users to have usernames as opposed to emails. The issue is that if you use Display Name, b2c does NOT check if it's unique.

User sign id works for my purposes, but I have no way in my Blazor web app to see what the user name is, as it's saved as the User Principal Name, viewable in Azure.

Comment: But a display name is different from a username. do you need the display name ? you could just stick with username and it should be fine

Comment: Username is fine, but I have no way of pulling that information in Blazor. B2C only sends email and display name as claims that I can check. There's no function call to get User Principal name, as far as I can tell.

Comment: you should be able to customize the claims returned from b2c tho

Comment: You can customize claims from b2c, however, they do not have the 'User Principal Name' or 'Username' as an option. If I make a custom attribute to be returned as a claim, there is nothing to be done to ensure it is unique. I honestly find it really strange how b2c doesn't have something as simple as a username set up out the box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use custom policies: https://aka.ms/ief. Username is not returned in the token with User Flows.

Using custom policies, you can sign up the user using username, and return their username (signInNames.username attribute, shown as userPrincipalName in the Azure Portal) into the token.

You can quick deploy custom policies using my tool [here](https://aka.ms/iefsetup). And quick deploy the username sample using [this page](https://b2ciefsetupapp.azurewebsites.net/Home/Experimental) with the **sample folder name** `username-signup-or-signin`.

Comment: Fantastic tool, It really helped out a lot! I see now that the sign-in name is returned as a claim for the username SUSI custom policy. I still need to make some adjustments to the custom policy, but thanks for helping get me 95% of the way there.

Comment: Is there any way I can just generate the files and download them without uploading them directly to B2C?

Answer (score 2):

If you need any additional claim you need to enter in your **Azure AD BC** tenant and configure the *Application Claims* from your *User Flow*, in the following example the User flow is called **B2C_1_signupsignin**:

[image: Application Claims]

The above example, as you can see, lists all the *other* available claims, because dome claims are **always** returned, as the User Name.

You can configure the claim (mode) used to login in the *Identity Provider*:
[image: Identity Provider config]

Than the claims you receive are the following:

[image: Claims list]

But as you can see there isn't any `userPrincipalName` or `signinNames`.
This is a known issue in Azure AD B2C and including this claims from the user flow manifest doesn't work.
The only solution I've found is to upload your custom policy and add a:
`<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId = "signInName" />`

but this works only for **local accounts**.
If you want to add signin names also for external (social) accounts you need to map them, like:
`<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="upn" />`

look at the base source XML here:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-up-with-social-and-local-account

Comment: Thanks, this was definitely in the right direction. The tool Jas Suri posted really helps to get kickstarted on custom policies.