# Azure AD B2C claim for username sign up

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, msal-react

I have created a Azure AD B2C directory/tenant and created a new sign up/sign in user flow as per below:
[image]

Notice that the Identity Provider is set to user id signup (i.e. usernames).

I've created a user with the username hughbe.

[image: Registered users]

When I get a JWT access token using the following code:

```js
const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
const token = await instance.acquireTokenSilent({account: accounts[0], scopes: ...});
```

I only get the following idTokenClaims
[image]

Is it possible to configure Azure AD B2C to include a user's `username` field in the list of Application Claims? It doesn't appear in the list:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

In my B2C tenant, I created one **Sign up and sign in** user flow with **same** properties as you like below:

[image]

Now, I created one Azure AD B2C user with username as **`sri`** like below:

[image]

When I ran the user flow, it displayed sign in screen with **username** as below:

[image]

If the user signs in **successfully**, they got **`code`** in their address bar along with **redirect Uri** like this:

[image]

I used the above **`code`** to generate token via **Postman** like below:

[image]

When I decoded this token, I got the **same claims** as you like below:

[image]

Please **note** that, it's not possible to include user's **`username`** field in the list of Application Claims.

While running **user flows**, **`username`** won't be returned as token claim.  Alternatively, you can make use of **custom policies** by adding **`signinname`** as output claim in the policy like below:

```xml
<OutputClaim  ClaimTypeReferenceId="signinname" />
```

**References:**

[SignUpOrSignin with_Username policy - GitHub](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/username-signup-or-signin/policy/SignUpOrSignin_Username.xml) by **Sipower**

[Send the user principal name via claims - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69155737/for-azure-b2c-is-there-a-way-to-send-the-user-principal-name-via-claims) by **Jas Suri-MSFT**